# How can I clone an input that uses the Masked Input plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, clone, maskedinput

I'm using jQuery's [Masked Input plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) to help users enter valid input for fields like dates, zip codes, phone numbers, etc. (I'm also using [Validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) to ensure the form can't be submitted unless things are correct and to offer hints.)

My problem is that I need to be able to clone a row of inputs, which include those using Masked Input. Normally, jQuery's `clone(true)` will copy any bound events along with the cloned DOM nodes, but for some reason, this doesn't work with Masked Input: clicking in the cloned input causes it to focus on the original one.

I see that [the plugin's author has also had this problem](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/clone-true-and-masked-input-plugin), but as far as I know, it hasn't been solved yet.

**Does anybody have a workaround?** I think  I could call `unmask()` on the new input, then do `mask()` again to apply the rules from the original, but I don't want to hardcode what those rules are; I want them to be determined from the original input so that I only have to code them in one place.

Comment: could you put the html code you want to see the structure clone thanks

Answer (score 0):

working with the template plugin jQuery, basic example:

JS:

```
var 
  id = 0,
  addNewItem = function() {

   var 
       itemNew =  $('#template-item').tmpl({id: id};

   id++;

   $(itemNew).find('.input-a').XPlugin(); // applied any plugin

   $(itemNew).appendTo('#myTable tbody');

  };
```

for use anywhere. or when an event occurs

```
addNewItem();
```

**Edit and Update the problem**

The problem is the following, this plugin saves the element reference (input) in the variable "`var input = $ (this);`" (line 85 of "jquery.maskedinput-1.2.2.js"), then uses it to all events and functions. When you want to clone the element, within the plugin, refers to the first element. For this reason this plugin can not be cloned.

Comment: When you say "working with," do you mean "I have tried creating new inputs with Masked Input applied using this method and it's working," or do you mean "in this example I'll be working with the template plugin, but I haven't tested it in your specific situation?"

Comment: much analysis of "working with" just having nothing of example, I proposed a way to implement the plugin without having to clone

Comment: OK. For now, I'm using a workaround of doing `.clone(false)`; that is, not cloning the event listeners, then applying new ones to the cloned inputs. But the ideal is to not have to specify anything in addition to "here's how my original inputs should be set up" and "I want another one." Both my temporary solution and the templates you suggest involve some repetition - "apply these plugins to the old ones, apply the same to the new ones", etc.